Past perfect continuous with different conjunctions

I was reading when/before she came in

I had been reading when/before she came in


3)I was reading by her arrival

I had been reading by her arrival

I was reading by the time she came

I had been reading by the time she came


By asking some questions here, I understand that 4 and 6 are wrong or just unidiomatic. I'd like to ask why. What makes my 2 example correct that 4 and 6 miss?

You're comparing two activities here, and the comparison is time based. One thing was happening before another thing, or at the same time (when). By is not a time based conjunction in the same way. You can say something like I finished work by the time he arrived, but that only makes sense because you are adding the time marker to the conjunction. By alone is more often a place conjunction: We walked by the public gardens. By here equals alongside.

I think presenting a list of made up sentences without context, and asking whether they're "valid" or not, is just a pointless version of Off Topic proofreading.

I mentioned in this answer that "by her arrival" and "by the time she came" are pretty much equal, so 4 and 6 are the same. In fact, this question is very similar to that one. I think this one is better because it focuses on a concern and explains rather than just saying "I think this is right, is it?" Try to do the same (or explain even more!) in future questions.

I think any unidiomatic choices here aren't so much about the verb tenses as about the specific words used. (For instance—it's a red herring—but while I mentioned that "by her arrival" means the same as "by the time she came," the second just feels more natural.)
As you say, 6 doesn't work well (and neither does 4, which is the same thing). But "I had already started reading by the time she came" is fine, as long as the situation makes sense of it. Maybe there was going to be a read-aloud story time scheduled, and "she" came late.
Comparing "I had started reading" to "I had been reading," the verb tenses are the same. I think sometimes you're hoping to formulate a list of verb tenses that do or don't work with certain time frames. But what made the difference here was a different idea. "I was reading" is an ongoing activity; "I started reading" is a single discrete action. Why don't 4 and 6 work? Because of the ideas you're trying to say. You're assembling a time line: Some reading happened, and someone arrived. We use "by the time" when comparing two events in time: X happened by the time Y happened. X must land on the timeline before Y:

We use other phrases to describe other time relationships. Like "X was happening when Y happened": The present continuous doesn't create a nice discreet dot; it creates a blurry span of time. We're not being at all clear about when X started or stopped, just that Y fell during it.

The "by the time Y happened" phrase doesn't work well with this chart, because "by the time" compares two points, and here we have one point and one undefined span. It's hard to say "X was happening by the time Y happened," unless we have some special circumstances that make it appropriate. I can think of a few ("The stars were coming out by the time we got home"), so I'm not going to say it's impossible... just that there are many circumstances where we don't use it, because it's not a tool meant for this job.
So "I had been reading when she came" simply takes the "blurry span" timeline, and looks at it from a point even farther on, so that the events are in the past:

So "I had been reading by the time she came" is no more idiomatic than "I was reading by the time she came." It has the same problem: it's using a "two points" construction to talk about a point plus a span. Shifting it from present perfect to past perfect does nothing to address that.
